# ACF Show Image field in a widget

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

**Orignal Code**

```
<h5 class="entry-title"><a href="'.esc_url(get_permalink()).'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h5>
```

**I want to add this code that ACF image field to show and it replaced on  title**

```
<?php $shortlinestory = get_field( 'shortlinestory' ); ?>
<?php if ( $shortlinestory ) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $shortlinestory['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $shortlinestory['alt']; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

My Custom image field name is **shortlinestory** in a widget i want to show the recent image please help me thanks

Comment: Hi Khan, did my answer help you out?

Comment: No i tried but the widget is not picking up the image file

Answer (score 1):

To get the custom field of a widget you have to add an additional parameter in the `get_field()` function. Advanced Custom Fields has pretty decent documentation and it is explained [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-widget/) how to do that.

First you have to figure out the ID of the widget. This is passed to the function that creates the widget for example `$widget_id = $args['widget_id']`. Then you can use `the_field('field_name', 'widget_' . $widget_id)` to get the custom field value.

Hope that helps you out, good luck!